# How to set column Width to BestFit when using OpenXml.Spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk, column-width

I am creating an xlsx file and trying to set the column width to the best width (depending on a font, e.g. "Calibri", and a fontsize, e.g. 10), which would be in my case just the length of the header title of the column. I am using `OpenXml` and working with `net-Core`.

I know that it doesn't work with `MeasureString` and `AutoFit` since for which I need to include `System.Drawing` which would result in overloads of e.g. `new Font`.

I also found the methods `BestFit` ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.column.bestfit?view=openxml-2.8.1)) and `Width` ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.column.width?view=openxml-2.8.1)) which I probably need to use somehow.

```
Columns columns = new Columns();

// headerTitles is just some list of strings which should define the length of the column
foreach (string columnName in headerTitles)
{

    // somehow I need to include this
    FontName ftn = new FontName();
    ftn.Val = "Calibri";
    FontSize ftsz = new FontSize();
    ftsz.Val = 10;

    // here the Width should be the width_of_column or something like AutoFit
    // ! width_of_columnName is what I am looking for !
    columns.Append(new Column() { Min = 2, Max = 2, Width = width_of_columnName, CustomWidth = true });
}

worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(columns);
```

I am really struggeling with this. I know that it is easy when using `System.Drawing` but with `OpenXml` and in `net-core` I could not find any working solution.

I hope someone can help.

I am very new to C#.

Comment: Here's a very useful tool that will help solve most issues of this nature: the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool. Create a very simple spreadsheet, with one column, the required formatting applied. Save and close. Now open it with the Tool. This will produce the Open XML SDK code to create this workbook from scratch. You can drill down until you find exactly the section of code you're interested in.

Comment: Another way is to create the sheet without the formating, save. Apply the formatting and save to a different file name. Now open the first version with the Tool and use the COMPARE functionality on the second. This gives you the code to produce the second from the first, which could also be helpful.